# ¿Cómo insertar array enviado por ajax con Laravel?

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo el siguiente problema. Envío por ajax a un controlador de laravel una variable llamada datos, la cual lleva lo siguiente:

```
0: {name: "_token", value: "1JkH3E87SFkagvgb5ZmlhwSGMX0v9yZAg7XvavM5"}
1: {name: "patient_id", value: "1"}
2: {name: "date", value: "2018-11-12"}
3: {name: "subtotal", value: "250"}
4: {name: "discount", value: "0"}
5: {name: "total", value: "250"}
6:
  orderArr: Array(1)
   0:
     cost: "250"
     description: "test"
     diagnosis_id: "43"
     tooth_id: "4"
     tooth_treatment_id: "15"
```

La primera parte se inserta en la tabla treatment_plans, lo cual si logro insertar.

El array orderArr debo de insertarlo en la tabla detail_treatment_plans, y lo he intentado insertar de la siguiente forma pero no lo logro, los valores son recibidos nulos por la base de datos:

```
DB::table('detail_treatment_plans')->insert([
                    'treatment_plan_id' => $treatment_plan->id,
                    'tooth_id' => $request->orderArr['tooth_id'],
                    'diagnosis_id' => $request->orderArr['diagnosis_id'],
                    'tooth_treatment_id' => $request->orderArr['tooth_treatment_id'],
                    'cost' => $request->orderArr['cost'],
                    'description' => $request->orderArr['description']
                ]);
```